# Jquery add percent sign to input box

Tags: jquery

I'd like to have an input box that automatically adds a visible percent sign to the user when entering numbers (not just recognizes it as a percent when submitting). Thus, a user hits "2" and sees "2%"

I'm assuming one could use Jquery to do this fairly easily, but I have no idea how! Any ideas?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 16):

You can handle the `change` event:

```
$(':input.Percent').change(function() {
    $(this).val(function(index, old) { return old.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') + '%'; });
});
```

Comment: How to add commas and dots to the regular expression?

Answer (score -1):

On Keyup event

```
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which != 13) { //13 is enter, you dont want to submit the form on enter
      var value = $.trim($(this).val());
      if(value != '') {
         $(this).val(value +'%');
      }
    } else {
         return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This would add multiple % signs for multiple keystrokes, would it not?