# HTML5: Append spinnerInput value with percentage symbol

Tags: html, spinner, percentage

I need to append the percentage symbol to the spinnerInput, which is displayed below

[image]

<`input type="number" min="0" value="0" step="5" onkeydown="return false"` >

The value in the textbox should be 45% as opposed to just 45

Syntax:

What is the best way to implement that (without using jQuery)?

Comment: Javascript:   **value+'%'**

Comment: Oh! I wish it was that simple. 
That's the first thing I tried. It does not work that way for the value in spinnerInput.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2678064/4812515

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2913236/4812515

Comment: That is using jQuery, I need to know if there is any functionality in HTML5 that allows to inculcate the symbols or rather takes input type as percentage.